# How do I cut bookmarked lines in multiple files with notepad++

Tags: ide, notepad++

How do I cut or remove bookmarked lines in multiple files with notepad++? I have 30 files and it would go much quicker if I could remove them all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Search → Bookmark → Cut Bookmarked Lines**

While this method only works for a single file at a time, it should help make the process a bit faster.

[image: Cut Bookmarked Lines]

For convenience, you can also set a keyboard shortcut using **Settings → Shortcut Mapper...**

[image: Shortcut Mapper]